# How to define a set of "restricted" vectors?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $N$ be an arbitrary set, and let $S\subset N$ be a proper subset of $N$. Further, let $\Delta\subset\mathbb{R}^N$ be some set of $N$-dimensional real-valued vectors. I am looking for a formal way to define the set of $S$-dimensional real-valued vectors all whose entries coincide with the entries of some vector $x\in\Delta$. I have thought of defining my set of interest as follows:

$\Delta(S)=\{\tilde{x}\in\mathbb{R}^S\mid\exists x\in\Delta:\forall i\in S,x_i=\tilde{x}_i\}$

*Is my attempt at defining the set I'm interested in a proper way of defining it? Assuming it's correct, does there exist a better way of defining this set?*

Thank you all very much!

**EDIT** In light of the first comment, let me provide a few of examples.

(1) Let $N$ and $S$ satisfy $N=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $S=\{1,2\}$. Suppose that $\Delta=\{(0,1,1,2),(1,3,5,1),(2,2,0,1),(3,1,2,0)\}$. Then, $\Delta(S)=\{(0,1),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)\}$.

(2) Let $N$ and $S$ satisfy $N=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $S=\{1,4\}$. Suppose that $\Delta=\{(0,1,1,2),(1,3,5,1),(2,2,0,1),(3,1,2,0)\}$. Then, $\Delta(S)=\{(0,2),(1,1),(2,1),(3,0)\}$.

(3) Let $N$ and $S$ satisfy $N=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $S=\{2,3\}$. Suppose that $\Delta=\{(0,1,1,2),(1,3,5,1),(2,2,0,1),(3,1,2,0)\}$. Then, $\Delta(S)=\{(1,1),(3,5),(2,0),(1,2)\}$.

(4) Let $N$ and $S$ satisfy $N=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $|S|=2$. Suppose that $\Delta=\mathbb{R}^4$. Then, $\Delta(S)=\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: I see some points of confusion here. 1) Are $S$ and $N$ really intended as sets, or just as positive integers? The fact that you speak of vectors as being members of $\mathbb{R}^N$ or $\mathbb{R}^S$ suggests the latter. 2) The notion of "a vector whose entries coincide with those of another" is a bit ambiguous. Suppose $x=(1,2)$ and $\Delta=\mathbb{R}^4$. Would $(1,2,0,0)$ be an element of your set? What about $(0,0,1,2)$ or $(0,1,0,2)$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Re (1): the sets $S$ and $N$ can be thought of sets of natural numbers (i.e., $S\subset N\subset\mathbb{N}$). Re (2): I'm not sure I understand it, but please see the edit in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the projection of $\Delta$ onto $\mathbb{R}^S$.  That is, let $\pi_S:\mathbb{R}^N\to\mathbb{R}^S$ be defined by $$\pi_S(x)_s=x_s\text{;}$$ that is, the $s$<sup>th</sup> component of $\pi_S(x)$ is the same as the $s$<sup>th</sup> component of $x$, and there are no other components.  Then your $\Delta(S)$ is just $$\pi_S(\Delta)$$

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote looks correct.

An alternative way of writing it would be

$$\{x\restriction S\;\mid\;x\in\Delta\},$$

where $f\restriction A$ denotes the restriction of the function $f$ to a subset $A$ of its domain.  (Here we're thinking of a member of $\mathbb R^N$ as a function from $N$ to $\mathbb R.)$

The two ways of writing it mean the same thing; I see no particular advantage to one way or the other.

(By the way, some authors write restriction as $\;\mid\;$ instead of $\;\restriction\;,$ so you may have seen that notation instead.)